# Selectively measuring AC magnetic fields with a Hall sensor (and getting an accurate Tesla reading)

Tags: arduino, measurement, electromagnetism

Is it possible to only measure AC electromagnetic fields in the 40 Hz — 120 Hz range with a resolution of 0.01 µT using a Hall effect sensor? If so, how would one go about doing it, and what particular Hall effect sensor should I be using?

Comment: You may want to consider using an inductor (coil) to pick up only the AC component of a magnetic field.

Comment: Yes, that ocurred to me, but it seems that getting an accurate reading with an inductor is difficult. Can you give me an example of measuring AC EMFs in Gauss/Tesla with a coil?

Comment: Btw, what do you actually want to measure? The field's amplitude? Peak-to-peak strength? Its wave form? Do you care about the influence of stray static magnetic fields (earth, loudspeakers, ...)?

Comment: I want to measure the flux density in Tesla and I would like to filter out constant background magnetic radiation, such as the earth and rare earth magnets.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is purely theoretical.

I see no additional problems with measuring a slowly varying magnetic field with Hall sensor - the output voltage will be a slowly varying signal.

However, due to Hall effect being a capacitance effect, there is intrinsic low pass filtering nature to a Hall sensor. It should not be an issue in at the frequencies of interest to you, but worth watching for in higher frequencies applications.

The accuracy of Hall sensor at low frequencies should be approximately the same as at constant field. Check the specs.

**Inductor alternative:**

I don't think that using an inductor is a good approach. Hall sensors are small and accurate, whereas inductors tend to be large and messy. The inductor has an intrinsic DC filtering capability, but this is not a major advantage.

If you can find a sensor based on induction which fits your application - go for it. However, I suggest you don't try to build one yourself (maybe for fun and education, but not for real applications) - it will certainly be worse than almost any hall sensor you can buy for a few bucks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! How would I filter out the constant fields? Should I do it arithmetically with for example an arduino or electronically? Also, would it, in fact, be _better_ to use an inductor, as Hanno originally suggested?

Comment: @user28058, if you want to know how to read AC voltages effectively I suggest you'll ask another question because the answer is not directly related to your original question. I'm adding my opinion on using an inductor in the body of the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much of a problem measuring magnetic fields with a coil. The basic theory is: -

Induced voltage = \$-N\frac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ where N is number of turns.

And if you are trying to pin-point flux density you'll need to ensure the cross sectional area of the coil is small enough. If that is achievable then the formula becomes: -

Induced voltage = \$-N\times S\frac{dB}{dt}\$ where B is flux density and S is area of coil.

For improved sensitivity the coil (N turns) can be wound on ferrite with high permeability and the new formula becomes: -

Induced voltage = \$-N\times S\times \mu_r \frac{dB}{dt}\$ where \$\mu_r\$ is the relative permeability of the ferrite material.

Using ferrite should certainly give some improvement but the permeability of the ferrite material is less certain and you would probably need to "calibrate" it with a known magnetic field. However, if you are chiefly interested in resolution this is not a big issue.

You are looking for a resolution of 0.01\$\mu T\$ at the lowest frequency of 40Hz. That's a \$\frac{dB}{dt}\$ numerically of 1.6\$\times 10^{-6}\$ - I'm assuming the change in B is over a period of 6.25ms i.e. one-quarter of the period of 40Hz.

Let's say you had 50 turns on a ferrite with a relative permeability of 10,000 and your coil had a cross-sectional area of 78.54 sq mm (coil diameter 10mm).

The induced voltage will be \$-50\times 78.54 \times 10^{-6}\times 10,000\times 1.6 \times 10^{-6}\$ = -63\$\mu V\$

At 120Hz, the induced voltage will be 3 times bigger. This signal can be easily amplified by virtually any decent op-amp and Low-pass filter set to reduce out-of-band noise. I can't compare this with Hall sensors because I don't know enough about them.

I think 3E7 material from Ferroxcube looks pretty good for this job. Notable is the stable permeability across the temperature range 20ºC to 40ºC. It has an initial permeability of 15,000.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This was really intresting to read. So well-written it could have been in a textbook! I'm going to be trying both the coil and the Hall effect approach... Thanks!